# Accessing Fields and modifying javascript after parsing

Tags: firebase, object, google-cloud-platform, javascript-objects

Code:

```
var string = JSON.stringify(stringValue);
var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
```

Ouput:

> {User1: {…}} User1 : CompanyName : "qwe" DriverName : "Tata Sky"
>   LicenseKey : "TATAA-0ITG6-BRHRL-UGT3E" LicenseType : "Demo" MACID : ""
>   Status : "False"

This is Background sometimes becomes user1, user2 and soon depending onsearch.once getting the object I need to update status and MACID fields.
How to create a dynamic refernce to that fields inspite of user1, user2... I must be able to access status & macid fields.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to access an unknown, dynamic key in a JavaScript object:

```js
var object = {User1: {CompanyName : "qwe", DriverName : "Tata Sky", LicenseKey : "TATAA-0ITG6-BRHRL-UGT3E", LicenseType : "Demo", MACID : "", Status : "False"}};

var user = object[Object.keys(object)[0]];

console.log(user);
```

So the key here is `var user = object[Object.keys(object)[0]]`, which looks up the value of the first key in the JavaScript `object`.

---

Since you tagged with `firebase`, I assume this value might come from the Firebase Realtime Database. In that case an alternative is to use the `DataSnapshot.forEach` method to loop over the children of the snapshot returned from a read operation. E.g.

```
firebase.database()
  .ref("users")
  .orderByChild("CompanyName")
  .equalTo("qwe")
  .once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
      console.log(userSnapshot.key); // "User1"
      console.log(userSnapshot.val().Status); // "False"
      userSnapshot.ref.update({ MACID: 1234, Status: "Yes" });
    });
  })
```